# How to have different line spacing for user-created and automatic line breaks

Tags: line-spacing

I use sharelatex Academic CV template and have spent hours but failed to find how to do this.  I have a block of text without any user-created line breaks but that span multiple lines and so has automatically-created line breaks. I end this block of text with my user-created line break.

I have a series of these text blocks.  These are references of my articles.  I want each reference (each block of text) to stick together visually but have some space between the block (i.e., for each reference to be differentiated from other references).

Let me demonstrate it in text format how I want it to look:

> Doe, J. (2012). Brainwashing and totalitarian influence. In V. S. Ra-
>   machandran (Ed.), Encyclopedia of Human Behavior (2nd Ed.) (pp. 406-412). San Diego, CA: Elsevier Academic Press.
>
> Doe, J., & Buddy, C. (2011). Initial impressions of others. In K. Deaux & M. Snyder (Eds.), The Oxford handbook of Personality and Social Psychology
>   (pp. 337-366). New York: Oxford University Press.

I'm aware that I can manually insert a vertical space.  However, it will get inefficient as I will have to do this for a lot of such references.

This is the preamble to my CV:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=5.5in, textheight=8.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\setlength\parindent{0in}
\linespread{1.03} %Adil added this to change linespacing, default is 1


% FONTS
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}, Variant=01]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Monaco}
%%% modified by Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}, Variant=01,
  BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf
]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{\scriptsize #1}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large} 

% PDF SETUP
% ---- FILL IN HERE THE DOC TITLE AND AUTHOR
\usepackage[%dvipdfm, 
bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
% ---- FILL IN HERE THE TITLE AND AUTHOR
    pdftitle={S. Adil Sarıbay - vita},
    pdfauthor={S. Adil Sarıbay},
    pdfproducer={http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}
]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue}
```

And this is a sample little section:

```
    \section*{Publications}

\subsection*{Journal articles}
\years{2015} Günsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutaş, M. (2015).  Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, honor, and Facebook. \emph{European Journal of Social Psychology, 45}, 323-335.\\
\years{2012} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Uleman, J. S. (2012).  Primed self-construal, culture, and stages of impression formation. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue on Culture as Process], 43 (4),} 196-204.\\
Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kressel, L. (2012).  Controversies, questions, and prospects for spontaneous social inferences. \emph{Social and Personality Psychology Compass, 6 (9),} 657-673.\\
```

The parskip suggestion kind of worked but it also partially messed up the alignment between the \years and the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might be a case for `\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}`

Comment: Maybe just using the `parskip` package will suffice? It replaces regular indented paragraphs with paragraphs delimited by blank lines. So if each of your blocks is a simple paragraph, then `parskip` will insert a blank line automatically between them.  If you are generating the references using `natbib` or `biblatex`, however, or if they are in some sort of list structure, then the answer will be different.  You need to show us a tiny complete document that shows what you are doing for us to help you.

Comment: If you insert manual line breaks anyway, you might just define a macro doing that and adding the extra space. Apart from that, the efficiency difference between typing `\\` and `\\[1ex]` for all references is (especially with copy+paste) not so big. As @AlanMunn pointed out, a MWE can possibly show whether there are better solutions than those already provided in the comments.

Comment: note that is (I hope!) not an inserted line break (`\\ ` or `\newline` or `\linebreak`) but rather a paragraph break (blank line or `\par`) in which case tex has a parameter to set the inter-paragraph space as shown by egreg in the first comment.

Comment: use of `\\ ` outside tables is almost always wrong:-)

Comment: What should I used instead of {\\} and how does it change anything?

Comment: It would be easier to suggest (and test) code for answers if you fixed your example to be a complete document that showed the problem rather than two unconnected fragments that can't be used directly.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  Do you want me to post the complete code for my document?  I already tried the suggested answer (parskip) and reported the result.  The other suggestion (\\[1ex]) is manual and I guess I can do that and there is nothing better so far.

Comment: a `\\ ` is a linebreak within a paragraph but you want an end of paragraph (just a blank line in the source) which is better markup and tex has a built in mechanism for supplying vertical space between paragraphs so the solution to your question is trivial (egreg's first comment) if you use `\\ ` then linespacing will be the same as automatic line break (as in fact it _is_ a normal automatic line break, `\\ ` just strongly encourages the line breaker to choose that point.

Comment: you don't have to post the code of your _real_ document but examples should be complete code that people can copy and run see how egreg's answer has a complete document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `\parskip`, but this needs a minor modification to `\years` so the `\marginnote` appears when the paragraph has already started. I set `\parskip` only locally, for the list of publications.

I also reorganized your preamble to have all packages first and settings later. Note that `xltxtra` and `xunicode` should not be loaded; just `fontspec`.

***Never*** use `\\` for ending a paragraph. It should only be used in contexts where it makes sense, that is, where you have to explicitly mark new lines, such as `tabular` or `flushleft`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
  % ---- FILL IN HERE THE TITLE AND AUTHOR
  pdftitle={S. Adil Sarıbay - vita},
  pdfauthor={S. Adil Sarıbay},
  pdfproducer={http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}
]{hyperref}  

% FONTS

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}, Variant=01,
  BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf
]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}

% ---- SETTINGS
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=5.5in, textheight=8.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\setlength\parindent{0in}
\linespread{1.03} %Adil added this to change linespacing, default is 1
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue} 

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\years}[1]{%
  \par\leavevmode\marginnote{\scriptsize #1}\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large} 

% PDF SETUP
% ---- FILL IN HERE THE DOC TITLE AND AUTHOR

\begin{document}

\section*{Publications}

\subsection*{Journal articles}

\begingroup\setlength\parskip{1ex}

\years{2015} Günsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutaş, M. 
(2015).  Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, honor, and Facebook. 
\emph{European Journal of Social Psychology, 45}, 323-335.

\years{2012} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Uleman, J. S. (2012).  Primed self-construal, 
culture, and stages of impression formation. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue on Culture as 
Process], 43 (4),} 196-204.

Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kressel, L. (2012).  
Controversies, questions, and prospects for spontaneous social inferences. \emph{Social and Personality 
Psychology Compass, 6 (9),} 657-673.

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's swell.  I tried it and with that couple lines of code (begingroup-endgroup) I was able to format a whole ton of publications and presentations. Thank you very much also for fixing my preamble (it was provided by sharelatex).  Cheers!

Comment: Regarding your comment: "Note that xltxtra and xunicode should not be loaded".  When those are gone, then the "XeTeX" in the "Typeset in XeTeX" indication at the bottom of the end of the document disappears.  So, I added those back :-)

Comment: @Adil The logo is provided by `metalogo`; I should have said that `xunicode` should not be loaded and `xltxtra` only if you really need its functions.